# Backbone Model from Hub in SignalR

Tags: asp.net-mvc, backbone.js, signalr

How can i create/convert this script into model in Backbone that can use SignaR Hubs? For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // Proxy created on the fly
        var chat = $.connection.chat;

        // Declare a function on the chat hub so the server can invoke it
        chat.addMessage = function (message) {
            alert("message");
        };

        // Start the connection
        $.connection.hub.start();
    });
</script>
```

---

EDIT

I did come up with this:

```
    window.Message = Backbone.Model.extend({
    hub: undefined,
    initialize: function () {
        this.hub = $.connection.message;
    },
    addMessage: function (message) {
        alert(message);
    },
    connect: function () {
        $.connection.hub.start();
        var messages = this.hub.getAll();//get messages
    }
});
```

but this is not working due to the following error:

this error: :55885 Unexpected response code: 200

Comment: What have you tried so far? What difficulties did you encounter with your code? Your question seems more like a job description you would send to a web developer than something you would ask on StackOverflow.

Comment: From what I know about backbone.js it requires a restful URL so this more than likely won't work. In addition I’m not a big fan of backbone.js with ASP.NET MVC because it seems like Hammer Nail syndrome. ASP.NET MVC does a good job on its own with MVC. Where it’s lacking is binding data from Ajax calls, Knockout.js seems to be the better fit. Backbone isn’t bad at all it’s great but you end up duplicating your efforts MVC Server Side then MVC Client Side, or you circumvent MVC Server in favor of client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use default settings SignalR will first try to send a websockets poll to the server. The :55885 is simply the port number of your server. Websockets protocol expects a response status code of 101 (see http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/).

If running IIS, unless you run Windows 8 with ASP.NET 4.5 your webserver, it will not recognize a web sockets request and (begin speculation) treat it as a normal get request and return status code 200 (OK) (end speculation) which is an unexpected response in the eyes of the websockets initiator. When this happens SignalR falls back to longpolling instead.

This might not answer your question but it will help you understand the error you get (which is likely not the reason why your code doesn't work)

Comment: THX i just find this Open source project https://github.com/rickschott/fire-camp/tree/master/BackboneMVC3SignalR that helpt me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Also, check out http://srtsolutions.github.com/backbone.signalr/ which is a Backbone.js/SignalR integration Nuget package.